# hello, how can i save these values ​in a local storage? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to be able to continue playing next time when you close the browser.

````
let counter = 0;
let countPerSec = 0;        
let countPerFiveSec = 0;    
let countPer0_5Sec = 0;    

let limo_stand_plus = 1;         
let limo_stand_kosten = 4;       
let taxi_pro_sec = 1;         
let taxi_kosten_sec = 5;      
let gartenArbeit_all_five_sec = 25;          
let gartenArbeit_werkzeug_kosten = 25 ;      
let zeitungAustragen = 1;          
let zeitungFirmenKosten = 500;       
let mehrLimoStände = 0;
let mehrLImoStändeKosten = 1500;
let prestige_plus = 0;
let prestige_minus = 50000;```
````

Comment: I am grateful for any help :)    (it is a button clicker game )

Comment: What have you tried? This feels like it should be achievable just by reading the examples on some documentation: [MDN localStorage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: this is not a good practice. you should use an object for saving these variables. like this,        `{counter: 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Read more at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

In your example:

```
// Set values: 
localStorage.setItem("counter", counter)
localStorage.setItem("countPerSec", countPerSec)        
localStorage.setItem("countPerFiveSec", countPerFiveSec)    
localStorage.setItem("countPer0_5Sec", countPer0_5Sec)    
localStorage.setItem("limo_stand_plus", limo_stand_plus)         
localStorage.setItem("limo_stand_kosten", limo_stand_kosten)       
localStorage.setItem("taxi_pro_sec", taxi_pro_sec)         
localStorage.setItem("taxi_kosten_sec", taxi_kosten_sec)      
localStorage.setItem("gartenArbeit_all_five_sec", gartenArbeit_all_five_sec)          
localStorage.setItem("gartenArbeit_werkzeug_kosten", gartenArbeit_werkzeug_kosten)      
localStorage.setItem("zeitungAustragen", zeitungAustragen)           
localStorage.setItem("zeitungFirmenKosten", zeitungFirmenKosten)       
localStorage.setItem("mehrLimoStände", mehrLimoStände)
localStorage.setItem("mehrLImoStändeKosten", mehrLImoStändeKosten)
localStorage.setItem("prestige_plus", prestige_plus)
localStorage.setItem("prestige_minus", prestige_minus)

// Read values: 
localStorage.getItem("counter")
localStorage.getItem("countPerSec")        
localStorage.getItem("countPerFiveSec")    
localStorage.getItem("countPer0_5Sec")    
localStorage.getItem("limo_stand_plus")         
localStorage.getItem("limo_stand_kosten")       
localStorage.getItem("taxi_pro_sec")         
localStorage.getItem("taxi_kosten_sec")      
localStorage.getItem("gartenArbeit_all_five_sec")          
localStorage.getItem("gartenArbeit_werkzeug_kosten")      
localStorage.getItem("zeitungAustragen")           
localStorage.getItem("zeitungFirmenKosten")       
localStorage.getItem("mehrLimoStände")
localStorage.getItem("mehrLImoStändeKosten")
localStorage.getItem("prestige_plus")
localStorage.getItem("prestige_minus")
```

Comment: how can i put my values in localStorage.setItem(key, value); ?

Comment: editted my answer

Comment: Bare in mind, the result of `.getItem()` will be a string representation of the number passed in, so a `5` that's saved will come out as `"5"`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object and Store
`let counter = 0;`
`let countPerSec = 0;`
`let obj = {counter, countPerSec}; localStorage.setItem('record', JSON.stringify(obj))`